# REST GET Design For Optional Feature Param

Tags: rest, machine-learning, design-patterns

I have a predictive model that I am wrapping in a REST endpoint. Under the hood, the `/forecast` endpoint chooses one of hundreds of models to make the prediction based on the GET param `feature_name`.

We have a use case to get all predictions from all models with a single HTTP request. Should we:

1. Make `feature_name` optional, and if nothing is passed, return predictions for all models?
2. Make users pass a special word like `'all'` to `feature_name` if they want all the predictions?
3. Maintain two endpoints, `forecast` and `forecast_all`?
4. Something I haven't thought of?

Comment: Have you considered having `/forecasts` return all and have different endpoints for each model `/forecasts/model1`, `/forecasts/model2` etc? This wayt i's more like a specific resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of using an endpoint for `/foo/{id}` for singular items, and a separate `/foo/` to get a collection of all items is extremely common.

I would especially suggest looking into a standard formats for REST collections. [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) is a popular one.

I wrote [an article](https://evertpot.com/rest-embedding-hal-http2/) a while back about collections in REST services. Maybe it's also helpful for more context.